# Display Product ID in Static Block - Magento

Tags: magento

This is my first post here so I apologise for anything stupid I will make.
I have a Magento shop (with a theme installed on it)
On products page I have a static block showing the Product ID.
I have created the Phtml (product_id.phtml) file in which I have the following code:

```
$_prodID = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prodID );
echo  $_prodID ;
```

On the static block I call:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="product_id" template="myfolder/product_id.phtml"}}
```

OK, the problem is that the product ID does displays but just for the first time on a product page. After that, it doesnt matter if I navigate to another product, it will still show the ID of the first product. I have read here and other forums too and I am guessing that this is a cache problem. A fix can be to disable the cache on that particular static block but I dont know how to do that. Can someone help please.
Aaa.. and please explain for a newbie.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do this:

```
echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```

No need to init the product model again. 
Anyway - have you tried disabling your cache to see if the id changes?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and this is the only way I could make it to work. I have disable cache for BLOCK HTML.

Answer (score 0):

in static block

`{{block type="core/template" name="product_id" pid="1" template="myfolder/product_id.phtml"}}`

in product_id.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getPid();?>
```